# How to setup opserver monitoring by stack exchange?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

I'm having trouble understanding how to configure and install opserver project by stack exchange guys. Have anyone configure/install it? I wanting to use it only for MS SQL Servers and maybe i will try to config it for IIS servers (as webservers). The main thing is that i don't uderstand is after building the source with VS and deploy it as an IIS website i can't find the way to configure which SQL Servers have to look etc. I have already integrate it with the Domain in order to login with domain admin accounts.

If anyone has any idea please answer :)

Cheers,

ankso

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? What were the results? https://github.com/opserver/Opserver#monitoring-configuration

Comment: Hey mfinni I tried to follow the instruction but it's kind of unknown for me and i didn't understand exactly how to setup in order to monitor my SQL Servers. I tried to find where in the configuration files they give the names and the username/password but i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to the overall instructions.
https://github.com/opserver/Opserver#monitoring-configuration
Note these points:

> 1. The basic configuration implementation is via .json files, for which .json.example files are included in the /config directory of the
>      Opserver project. These .example files are exactly what’s running in
>      the Stack Exchange production environment, minus any passwords or
>      internal-only URLs.
> 2. We recommend using a service account with the necessary permissions for monitoring, this eliminates any passwords in your
>      configuration files and makes management easier
> 3. Even if you have correctly configured your monitors, you still may not see any data. Each monitor configuration has an enabled flag which
>      must return true for a monitor section to appear in OpServer.

For item 1, look at a SQL sample config file
https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/blob/master/Opserver/Config/SQLSettings.json.example

Make a copy of that and customize it with your connection strings.

For point 2, if you're using AD-integrated SQL logins and are using a service account for Opserver, you won't need usernames/passwords in the config file

Once you've done that, don't forget point 3.

Comment: You meen to run the IIS OpServer site with a network service account? Can you be more specific with this? I will check the other tomorrow and I will come back. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Correct. You'd run the app pool as an active directory account (say YourDomain\SQLMonitor) and create a login on the SQL instance(s) that you want monitored for that account using `create login [YourDomain\SQLMonitor] from windows;`. Now you don't need to put a password in the config file.

Comment: @BenThul if i have SQL Servers in different domains what i have to do? I have SQL for internal use and i have SQL instances for public usage (Cloud SQLs) and i'm wondering if i can monitoring them from the same opserver instance.

Comment: In that case, you will need passwords in your connection strings, yes.

Comment: @mfinni How can i do this? I mean this thing in my SQLSettings.json "connectionString": "Data Source=SQL01;Initial Catalog=bob;Integrated Security=SSPI;" how i have to do it in order to have work for me? Also i can't find the Point 3 you said on your answer. Where i mark this flag in $true?